# Grammatical error in the expression "what would occur without"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, conditionals, pied-piping

## Background

There is a system called YOLO which identifies objects in an image. For instance, YOLO can identify dog, bicycle, and car as objects in the image.

[image]

Internally YOLO uses a neural network model that outputs values (Ci, x, y, w, h), which is the information about an object that the model thinks it has identified. (x,y) is the coordinate and (w,h) is the width and height of the object.

### Situation

It seemed to me, the YOLO system could work without using Ci because I thought it can be calculated from (x, y, w, h) and the additional information of the objects themselves.

To clarify the purpose of **Ci** and if it is essential for YOLO to detect objects, I asked the [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606367/yolo-v1-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-confidence-ci) in [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

> Is Ci essential to the capability to detect objects? What would occur without?

There was a comment by the moderator to the question.

> Could you please elaborate on your question **"what would occur without?" That is so ungrammatical** as to present difficulties understanding what you are trying to ask.

### Question

I am not sure why it is ungrammatical. Please help understand why it is ungrammatical. In my understanding, it is the same with *What would occur to the capability of YOLO to detect objects without Ci*.

Someone provided an answer in a comment, and it turned out YOLO can identify the same object multiple times and can give redundant identifications, which would be the same with *redundant detections would occur without Ci*. This seems not ungrammatical and makes some sense to me. Please explain what grammatical error, if any, in *what would occur without.

### Note

The original [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606367/yolo-v1-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-confidence-ci) asked in the Cross Validated Stack Exchange has been updated based on the comment by a modelator.

Comment: Like @Greybeard (below) I find the moderator's comment immoderate. Sure, your sentence falls a little short of native-grammaticality, but I think it is entirely comprehensible in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Ci essential to the capability to detect objects? What would occur without?

"Without" is a preposition, and it requires an object. It can't be a stranded preposition with "what" as its object (as in "What could he live without?"), since "what" is already being used as the subject of "would occur."

So you need to add an object: "What would occur without **it**?" Alternatively: "What would occur without **Ci**?"

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. Allow me to follow up. So grammatically **it** or **Ci** cannot be omitted as it is required by ```without``` preposition, hence the sentence is ungrammatical?

Comment: @mon Yes, that is why.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood.

Comment: Except [without](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/without) is also an adverb and can be used without a noun following. It's best known in set phrases such as [go without](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20without): "If you can't afford a new car, you'll just have to go without." But there are several of these (do without, etc), and it can be used more generally

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your coffee with sugar or without?

This works as there is a clearly implied "sugar" as the object of "without".

In your sentence the implied object can be "Ci" or (less likely) "the capability to detect objects."

That said, I find the "ungrammatical" response a little pedantic.